# How to use REGEX_REPLACE to search and replace partial strings in Teradata

Tags: regex, replace, teradata

How to use REGEX_REPLACE to search and replace partial strings in Teradata. I want to be able to search a partial string and replace it with space.

For example , If my string has 'Walmart and Occurrence >0/Target and Occurrence >0', I want to be able to search just for 'Walmart' and replace the whole string with space. So my output should be '/Target and Occurrence >0'

Thanks

Comment: You're not replacing the whole string, it's a partial replacement. What are the rules? Is `> 0` a delimiter?

Comment: '/' is the Delimiter. So basically I have two strings separated by a '/'. 'Walmart and Occurrence >0' is string 1 and 'Target and Occurrence >0' is my second string. My requirement is to replace 'Walmart and Occurrence >0' to a space just by searching for 'Walmart'. And I can have multiple strings like these separated by /.

Comment: For example if my complete string is 'Walmart and Occurrence >0/Target and Occurrence >0/Walmart and Occurrence >3/Giant and Occurrence >2' then my output should be '/Target and Occurrence >0/ /Giant and Occurrence >2.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
regexp_replace(x, '[^/]*Walmart[^/]*', ' ',1,0,'i') -- case insensitive
regexp_replace(x, '[^/]*Walmart[^/]*')              -- case sensitive
```

Check if there's `'Walmart'` and then replace everything between the previous slash and the next slash with a space.